# How to get particular type of venue from list of venues, foursquare.

Tags: android, foursquare

By using this code i got all venue details,here i want perticular type of venue lets say 'Hotels' ,'Restaurants' how to specify in the following code.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=checkin&ll="
                + lat + "," + longi + "&client_id=" + client_id
                        + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&v="
                        + 20131008); //
```

Comment: Its not full example. What we see here is only how you create URL. What do you want to do? parse XML? Json on response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this modified url to fox this issue.in url we can directly filter the venues.

```
try {
            httppost = new HttpGet(
                    "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=checkin&ll="
                    + lat + "," + longi + "&client_id=" + client_id
                            + "&client_secret=" + client_secret +"&query="+ URLEncoder.encode("Hotel|Bar|Club|Cafe|CoffeeShops", "utf-8")+ "&v="
                            + 20131008);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } //
```